# error while installing quadprog package in R for MAC

Tags: r, macos, quadprog

I'm trying to install the quadprog package in R in mac but it keeps showing this massage:

- installing *source* package ‘quadprog’ ...
  ** package ‘quadprog’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** libs
  gfortran-4.8   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c aind.f -o aind.o
  make: gfortran-4.8: No such file or directory
  make: *** [aind.o] Error 1
  ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘quadprog’
- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/quadprog’

Anybody know what I should do to have it installed?

Comment: `make` can't find  `gfortran-4.8` in your `PATH`. You haven't installed it. Go to `http://r.research.att.com` and go to the subdirectory `libs`. you will find `gfortran-4.82-......`. Download it and install it following the instructions in the R-admin manual.  But why don't you download the binary from CRAN?

Comment: Thanks @Bhas! Just followed what you recommended and It worked!

Comment: I had the same problem.  I upgraded R using the nightly builds at the address from @Bhas and now the problem is fixed.  thanks

Comment: Do realise that in 2019 R uses a more uptodate gfortran (6.1). See the macOS tools page on CRAN [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools) (valid if you are using the CRAN version of R).