# How to list out all installed R packages in Suse Linux 11 s3

Tags: r, suse

We have installed R 3.1.1 in my current hadoop HDP 2.1.5 and I want to add more additional R packages, I want to what are all packages are currently installed?

Comment: `installed.packages()`

Comment: Thanks  you sowmya

Comment: I have confusion that i just want to install spldf pkg it is asking depen of tseries and tseries depn of quadprog and while i installed quadprog ERROR display that make: gfortran command not found..is it gfortran and gcc-fortran are same // i have downlaod gcc-fortran rpm can i installed it..?

Comment: I guess it is `sqldf` package. Please check.

Comment: Please see this link for `quadprog` package installation:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136398/error-while-installing-quadprog-package-in-r-for-mac

Answer (score 1):

```
    # For checking the packages installed, use          
    > installed.packages() 
    > In_P <- installed.packages()[,1]

    # For checking all the available packages, use
    > available.packages()
    > Av_P <- available.packages()[,1]

    # Removing Installed packages from available packages list
    > Un_P <- Av_P[!Av_P %in% In_P]  

    # For installing Packages which are not installed already
    > install.packages(Un_P)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the `spldf pkg` is, I hope it is a typo for `sqldf`

```
# to install all packages and its dependencies simple use the below code.  
install.packages("Package_Name", dependencies= True).
```

Looks Like you are working with R-Hadoop. Sometimes the packages are not available on CRAN, you can download them and install them on your local computer and pass the path.

```
install.packages("path_to_installed_package.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

The following link may be helpful. 
Run an R job on Hadoop http://www.rdatamining.com/big-data/r-hadoop-setup-guide

Some useful packages for download https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki